# The method 'DefaultCacheManager' isn't defined for the class 'WallpaperImages'. flutter

Tags: flutter, naming

[image]

```
var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
```

I couldnt use this line to get file path of the url

Help me out

```html
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:59:22: Error: The method 'DefaultCacheManager' isn't defined for the class 'WallpaperImages'.
 - 'WallpaperImages' is from 'package:flutter_app_sample/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DefaultCacheManager'.
    var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

To use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager 
You can do `import`

```
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
```

and in `pubspec.yaml` add `flutter_cache_manager`

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_cache_manager: any
```